# flink - adding instrumentation

Tags: java, newrelic, apache-flink

I want to add **NewRelic** instrumentation to my flink jobs.  I don't see where it's possible to pass additional classpath / other params to the `bin/flink run <job>`  command.

The NewRelic java agent wants `-javaagent:<path to jar>` added to the execution path. Passing in the config file path is advisable as well.

---

### Edit:

I added this line to my *conf/flink-conf.yaml* on all (3) cluster machines:

```
env.java.opts: "-javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.file=/opt/newrelic/newrelic.yml"
```

When I go to start the cluster only the **job manager** will start. The **task manager** doesn't start on any of the machines.

The only way I've found to add instrumentation (so far) is to change the command line at the end of *bin/flink* to include the above parameters. This is fine except that it requires the session where the command was running to remain open. If you exit out, the Flink job keeps going but the NewRelic agent quits.

Comment: What does the `JobManager` log say when you start it with the modified `flink-conf.yaml`?

Comment: No error messages. The UI shows no tasks slots or tasks managers available.

Comment: My apologies - had the task and job managers backwards in my edit.

Comment: Ok, what does the `taskmanager.log` say on the different machines?

Comment: No log file is created.

Comment: Could you try to start a TaskManager manually with the `env.java.opts` set on the TaskManager nodes via `taskmanager.sh start`? You find the script in the `bin/` directory. If there are no logs, then this mean that the JVM has problems to be started, which is really odd.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95921/discussion-between-ethrbunny-and-till-rohrmann).

Comment: @ethrbunny trying to do something similar to find memory issues in Flink? Did adding relic agent work for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass additional JVM start-up parameters via the `env.java.opts` config value which you can set in Flink's configuration file `flink-conf.yaml`.

Comment: Is there a way to set this on a per-job basis? Each topology will have a distinct **newrelic.yml** file.

Comment: If you run the jobs sequentially on the same Flink cluster, then this is not possible. The reason is that the TaskManager and the JobManager are re-used for the different jobs. However, if you use YARN, then you can start the jobs in single-job mode, which starts up a YARN cluster for each job and terminates it when the job is done. For each these sessions you can define via dynamic properties `-Denv.java.opts=xyz` the configuration settings (se https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/setup/yarn_setup.html#run-a-single-flink-job-on-hadoop-yarn)

Answer (score 2):

First remove the quotes in the value(right side)

```
env.java.opts: -javaagent:/opt/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.file=/opt/newrelic/newrelic.yml
```

And also make sure that you put the files in "lib" directory of flink and rewrite the command as

```
env.java.opts: -javaagent:lib/newrelic.jar -Dnewrelic.config.file=lib/newrelic.yml
```

All the files in "lib" directory will be copied to job manager and task managers and available in the relative path "./lib"

Comment: Happy to hear that